# Assign unique int values to a word in a String then store it into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I'm trying to get the unique words within a string then storing it within an array along with the amount of times it occurs.

My approach towards this was to assign a unique integer to each unique string within an `if-else` statement, then taking the unique counts of those integers, and pulling any one word from the string that's assigned a unique value, and finally taking the number of times the unique integer occurs.

However, whenever I get to assigning a unique value to the `String` I get `null`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class StringLearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    final   String text = "Win Win Win Win Draw Draw Loss Loss";

    int[] numbers = null;
    
    
 if(text.equals("Win")) {
     numbers= new int[1];
    
 }else if(text.equals("Draw")){
     numbers = new int  [2];
    
 }else if(text.equals("Loss")) {
     numbers = new int [3];
     
 } 
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    

        }
        
    }
```

Expected output:

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3}
```

EDIT:
How could this be implemented in a general sense? Such that, I did not know the String had "Win, Loss, Draw" in the string, but I'd want to assign a unique integer to any given unique word?

Comment: "*`numbers= new int[1];`*" - This does not do what you think it does. I recommend reading a tutorial on the basic types, as well as one on arrays. Both are covered in [this tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Comment: This is so bad I don't think it counts as an "attempt" at code.  Please ask your instructor for help, they need to be aware that you are struggling this much.

Comment: @markspace I've been self-learning for the past 2 weeks so I'm rather new to the lexicon for java.

Comment: I think you need a more structured approach, maybe find an online course or community college or something, what you have above just doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Stackbeans – If there is currently no instructor you could ask then you should look for one! Sorry, but the code is really not an attempt for a solution of the described problem, by no means!!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I still have loads more to practice on and learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating an object of an array, the number in the brackets `new int[1]` you declare the length of the array. I'd recommend using a HashMap for that matter. An example of code would be:

```
public class StringLearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String text = "Win Win Win Win Draw Draw Loss Loss";

        HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String word : text.split(" ")) { // loops through each word of the string
            // text.split(" ") returns an array, with all the parts of the string between your regexes
            // if current word is not already in the map, add it to the map.

            if (!counts.containsKey(word)) counts.put(word, 0);

            counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1); // adds one to the count of the current word
        }
        // lambda expression
        counts.forEach((string, integer) -> System.out.printf("amount of \"%s\": %d\n", string, integer));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
amount of "Draw": 2
amount of "Loss": 2
amount of "Win": 4
```

---

Edit (response to tQuadrat):
I edited this post to keep everything clean and readable.

```
public class StringLearning {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String text = "Win Win Win Win Draw Draw Loss Loss";

        HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String word : text.split(" ")) { // loops through each word of the string
            // text.split(" ") returns an array, with all the parts of the string between your regexes
            // if current word is not already in the map, add it to the map.
            if (!counts.containsKey(word))
                counts.put(word, counts.size() + 1); // index of the word (+ 1 because your expected output was 1-indexed)

        }
        for (String word : text.split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(counts.get(word) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: You should not count the words, you should replace each word by a unique number representing it.

Comment: @tquadrat I am not often here, I don't know if you can see my edit so I'm telling you that I adapted the code to work as a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

you have many problems with your code.

first, you have to get each word of the string individual, so you need to `split` it into array.

second, you need to create one array, and in it to put the integers. (what you did is to create new array for each number)

I tried to fix the problems. hope you understand my code.
(I only fixed your code, and not make it generial)

```
 String[] arr = text.split(" ");
 int[] numbers = new int[arr.length];
    
 for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    
    if(arr[i].equals("Win")) {
         numbers[i] = 1;
    
     }else if(arr[i].equals("Draw")){
         numbers[i] = 2;
    
     }else if(arr[i].equals("Loss")) {
         numbers[i] = 3;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the problem(s9 and how our solution solves it.

Comment: @Turing85 – not to mention that the solution makes the (most probably invalid) assumption that the only valid words are "Win", "Draw" and "Loss" …

Comment: Welp, the last edit on the question made this answer invalid anyway....

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this approach:

1. Get the number of words in the String: `var words = text.split( " " );` This assumes that words are separated by blanks only.
2. Create registry for the words: `Map<String,Integer> registry = new HashMap<>();`
3. Create the result array: `var result = new int [words.length];`
4. Now loop over the words and check if you have seen the word already:

   ```
   for( var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i )
   {
       result [i] = registry.computeIfAbsent( words [i], $ -> registry.size() + 1 );
   }
   ```
5. Finally, print the result: `System.out.println( Arrays.toString( result ) );` – although this would use `[…]` instead of `{…}`.

`registry.computeIfAbsent( words [i], $ -> registry.size() + 1 );` adds a new entry to the registry for each unseen word and assigns the size of the registry plus one as the unique number for that word. For already known words, it returns the previously assigned number.

This works for any set of words in `text`.

So the complete thing may look like this:

```
public final class StringLearning 
{
  public static final void main( final String... args ) 
  {
    final var text = "Win Win Win Win Draw Draw Loss Loss"; // … or any other text
    final var words = text.split( " " );
    final Map<String,Integer> registry = new HashMap<>();
    final var result = new int [words.length];
    for( var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i )
    {
      result [i] = registry.computeIfAbsent( words [i], $ -> registry.size() + 1 );
    }
    System.out.println( Arrays.toString( result ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the unique value for each word of string in map and then fetch the unique value while assigning your array.

```
String text = "Win Win Loss Draw Hello";
String[] split = text.split(" ");

// To maintain unique value for each word of input string 
Map<String, Integer> = new HashMap<>();
int counter = 0;
for(String ele:split)
  if(!map.containsKey(ele))
    map.put(ele, ++counter)
 
// Getting unique value for each word and assigining in array
int[] array=new int[split.length];
for(int i=0; i<split.length;i++)
  array[i] = map.get(split[i]);
```